# Dynamic text tagging with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

What I couldn't figure out is how to dynamically tag ranges of text with the Tkinter text widget.
The idea is that when the user selects a range of text, it dynamically creates a tag to modify the style.
Here's my code:

```
#...code...
tag = text_field.tag_ranges(SEL)
text_field.tag_add('sizesel',tag[0],tag[1])
text_field.tag_config('sizesel',font = appFont)
```

This code is part of a callback function that is bound to a `Combobox`, so that the size of the text changes every time the value changes.

This code works great, but if I try to stylize a second line of text, it takes the style of the 1st line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a unique style for each range you'll need to use a unique tag, because style information belongs to the tag rather than the range of text. The easiest method is to keep a global (or instance attribute) counter that you increment each time you add a tag, and use that as part of the tag name.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it:

```
tag = text_field.tag_ranges(SEL)
i = 0
for i in tag:
    text_field.tag_add(i,tag[0],tag[1])
    text_field.tag_config(i,font = appFont)
```

as you can see I added a simple for statement that goes on tag which is the variable that contains the indexes for the SEL tag.